# fb:multi-friend-selector, can I use it for other than sending invites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

In my facebook application, I need an option, where users can add or remove the friends from a group. 
I see the

But all the samples I see only provides the option to send invite to application.

Is there any way to capture the selected ids from the control and perform the operation I need to do (add or remove the users from the group)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about programming your own interface for selecting friends?
Just execute this FQL query:

```
select uid,first_name,middle_name,last_name,pic_square from user where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Of course you can get other fields: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Once you get the list, you can build your own interface.